# How to reset the modal on every click of advance search using Angular

Tags: angular

I have disabled the search button, if there are no values in the field, as there is no mandatory field present over there. Now on every click of advance search, I am able to see the value which I have entered and clicked on search, so now I have to clear the values in advance search or the advance search model should be reset, but the values which is entered below the advance search link should retain. I am stuck here and unable to proceed further.

Typescript:

```
disableSubmit(): boolean {

    let disabled = true;
    const keys = Object.keys(this.advanceSearch);
    keys.forEach(key => {

        if (this.advanceSearch[key]) {

          disabled = false;
          return;
        }
    });
    return disabled;
  }
```

I have also pasted link of working demo: [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rttvxu?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

So at first it is not possible to return from inside of an `Array.forEach(...)` (see [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)).

Secondly calling a function directly in the HTML causes a lot of executions of it, because the function is executed every time the change detection is executed by Angular.

So I hope I understand your question correctly. You can store the enterd input in a separate array to access it in the HTML:

**app.component.ts**

```
...
list = [];
...    

getAdvanceSearchList() {
    console.log("submit...");
    const keys = Object.keys(this.advanceSearch);
    keys.forEach(key => {
        if (this.advanceSearch[key]) {
            const obj = {key: key, value: this.advanceSearch[key]};
            this.list.push(obj);
        }
    });
    // Reset your advanceSearch model here
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm rounded-pill mr-1" [hidden]="!item.value" 
        *ngFor="let item of list"> <!-- Use the list here and you don't need the keyvalue pipe -->
            {{item.value}}
            <i class="fas fa-times-circle" (click)="remove(item.key)"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for response, but sorry it is not working

Comment: reseting model is not working, i have used model here, so i need to reset the model?

Comment: Yes you need to reset the model. Sorry I thought my comment is understandable.

Comment: yes it is understandable, but i am struggling a bit to make it workthrough, give me sometime il come back

Comment: i have taken this advance search modal section from one component, and the value displaying below advance search is the parent component, with one model i am using both, so i am not able to remove nor reset the modal, this is the problem i am facing

Comment: It sounds like you've done larger changes on your code. I cannot help you without more information, but maybe [3 ways to communicate between Angular components](https://medium.com/@mirokoczka/3-ways-to-communicate-between-angular-components-a1e3f3304ecb) can help you.